# OnWindowFocusChanged and onCreate - Android

Tags: android

I am trying to setup the UI elements programatically. 
 I am able to setup the UI elements in **onWindowFocusChanged** method?  
The question i want to ask  is - shall i setup the UI elements in the **onCreate** method or on **onWindowFocusChanged**? The code -

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.baselayout);
}
```

And

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        res = getResources();
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        setUpBackgroundImage();// setting up the background image
        setUpTopMenu(); // Setting up the menu on top
        setUpLogo(); // Setting up the Logo
    }
}
```

Is the above approach correct?

Comment: Commonly in `onCreate()` or `onStart()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take note that some new devices are capable of showing multiple windows, `onWindowFocusChanged()` is not ideal place to initialize your layout. Use `onCreate()` to inflate layout and set up View variables.

Comment: In the scenario of multiple windows - if the current activity loses the focus, Will the views be visible?

Comment: @Anukool Yes they may be visible, [here's an example](http://youtu.be/tjHMEkBFhsg).

Comment: As per the documentation for onWindowFocusChanged- As a general rule, however, a resumed activity will have window focus... unless it has displayed other dialogs or popups that take input focus, in which case the activity itself will not have focus when the other windows have it

Comment: @Anukool That's what `onPause()` is for. Also, an Activity should worry about is own views/dialogs/popups and not about another windows.

Comment: The problem i am facing while setting up the UI in onCreate is- I have to set up the Logo at a relative position say 10 % margin top of the background. For this i have to calculate the height of the screen programatically and find out the 10 % of the height and setup the logo. In onCreate i am getting the height of the background image as  0 because the view is not yet drawn. That's the reason i was looking for a method like onWindowFocusChanged

Comment: @Anukool Just use `onResume()` ,OR, override [`onLayout()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/) of parent `ViewGroup`, set margins for that special child `view` (logo) according to current size, and then call default implementation `super.onLayout()`.

Answer (score 4):

`onCreate()`
This is the place where you setup your UI

`onWindowFocusChanged()`
This is called when all your layouts or UI have been successfully loaded or created properly.